# io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable in python

Tags: python

```
import sys
users = {}
status = ""
f = open("password.txt", "r")

while status != "q":
status = input("Are you a registered user? y/n? Press q       to quit: ")  

if status == "n": 
     createLogin = input("Create login name: ")

     if createLogin in users: 
         print("Login name already exist!\n")
     else:
         createPassw = input("Create password: ")
         users[createPassw] = createPassw 
         print("\nUser created!\n")
         f.write(createLogin)
         f.write(createPassw)
elif status == "y": 
    login = input("Enter login name: ")

    if login in users:
       passw = input("Enter password: ")
       print

       if login in users and passw in users: 
           print("Login successful!\n")

    else:

        print
        print("User doesn't exist!\n")
```

Getting:

```
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable
```

Why does this not let me write the username or password to the external file.

plz could you help fix my code or write a better version plz.

I want the code to be a basic account checker and then register if the person does not have an account.

Comment: You are opening the file in reading mode (`'r'`), hence it is not writable.

Answer (score 2):

Add writing and reading mode to `open()` function:

```
f = open("password.txt", "r+")
```

> file_object  = open(“filename”, “mode”)

The modes are:

- **r** – Read mode which is used when the file is only being read
- **w** – Write mode which is used to edit and write new information to the file (any existing files with the same name will be erased when this mode is activated)
- **a** – Appending mode, which is used to add new data to the end of the file; that is new information is automatically amended to the end
- **r+** – Special read and write mode, which is used to handle both actions when working with a file

Reference:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files